# Javascript EventListener disappears when another is created

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am trying to create a script where a select HTML object detects a change, gets its value and creates another tag to display based on its value. E.g. A user selects 'United Kingdom'  and a tag saying that appears in the div. This works, but I have an X-button for it that deletes the tag when clicked, using an `EventListener`. The problem is that I can only ever delete the final tag created, as the variables used to create each tag's id change, and so, only the last one works. Some of the code is below:

```
 document.getElementById("locations-editor-container1").innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById("locations-editor-container1").innerHTML+"<div 
    class='locations-editor-country-disp' id='"+country+"[@]'>"+country+"<svg  
   id='"+country+"[##]' class='locations-editor-x-button' 
   style='width:2vh;position:absolute;right:0.5vw;vertical-align:middle;' 
   viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path fill='#FFFFFF' 


      d='M19,6.41L17.59,5L12,10.59L6.41,
      5L5,6.41L10.59, 12L5,17.59L6.41,19L12,13.41L17.59,19L19,17.59L13.41,12L19,6.41Z'/></svg></div><br>";
            var countryId=country+"[##]";
            
     document.getElementById(countryId).addEventListener("click",function(){ remove(countryId)},false);
```

Comment: Hmm, how does `country` get defined? Is it getting incremented by `1` whenever you add the `locations-editor-container1` element? Also, what exactly does `remove()` do? Could you please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as that would help debug the problem :)

Comment: Hey, thanks. 2 seconds. Remove is the function to remove the tag. It runs fine and works when it does run, but with debugging I have found that it doesn't run for anything except the last tag

Comment: The first thing that I would do to solve this problem is to separate rendering from tags management logic. This will not only make your code more readable but it will be also a lot easier to debug.

Comment: var country = document.getElementById("locations-editor-selector").value; Country is the value of the selector when the function is called (on select change)

Comment: Okay, I'll do that so. Seperate rending from tags management

Comment: The problem appears to be that each event listener is deleted as another is added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is your error reproduced, because you are replacing innerHTML of some content you are removing the event listeners of the elements you are replacing. That is why only the last element works:

```js
const content = document.querySelector("#content");
var counter = 0;
const add = e => {
  content.innerHTML = 
      //you are replacing content, thus removing the event listeners of 
      //  previous elements
      content.innerHTML +
    `<div style="cursor: pointer;" id="div${++counter}">
        click me ${counter}
    </div>`;
  document.querySelector(`#div${counter}`)
  .addEventListener(
    "click"
    ,(x=>e=>{
      alert(`Counter for this div:${x}`);
    })(counter)
  );
}
document.querySelector("#myButton").addEventListener(
  "click"
  ,add
);
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="add">
```

The solution is to not replace the content but add the new item to existing content:

```js
    const content = document.querySelector("#content");
    var counter = 0;
    const add = e => {
      //create a div (will not be added to dom yet)
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = 
        `<div style="cursor: pointer;" id="div${++counter}">
          click me ${counter}
        </div>`;
      div
      .addEventListener(
        "click"
        ,(x=>e=>{
          alert(`Counter for this div:${x}`);
        })(counter)
      );
      //add element to dom (do not replace content)
      content.appendChild(div);
    }
    document.querySelector("#myButton").addEventListener(
      "click"
      ,add
    );
```

```html
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="add">
```